# Expresion regular para extraer una cadena

Tags: php

Buenas tardes necesito extraer de este html la siguiente cadena A62082

```
<td id="customfield_11400-475700-value" class="value" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="80%">
    A62082
</td>
```

el problema es que customfield_11400-475700 siempre cambia
en resumen lo que necesito es una expresion que extraiga todo lo que empiece con la letra A + los siguientes 5 numeros, siempre son numeros y siempre es la letra A con lo que empieza.

Comment: nose ni como empezar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ocupar testers en línea. A mi punto de vista, ésta expresión regular te serviría:

[A][0-9]{5}

[Muestra del funcionamiento](https://regex101.com/r/bWU8E2/1)